# SQL server 2008 table not being found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm going to deploy my ASP.NET web app on a production server, I've copied files (DLL & aspx files) and applied IIS settings, then restored my database (I had made a backup - BAK file - on my test server) in SQL server 2008 installed on the server. Afterwards set connection string in web.config file to point to the new settings. But after trying to run my website, I get an strange error:

```
Invalid object tblX
```

tblX is one of my tables (table used in first page of site). My database is fully restored in the new server (and all tables exist there), but I think there is a problem in user permissions corresponding this database. Also I tried to test database access with 'sa' user but again with no luck. What is going wrong? How should I create my user in SQL Server Management Studio so that all tables are accessible? (I use SQL Server authentication, i.e. I create a user (with password) in SQL Server management Studio and assign it to my restored database, then use DB/user info in my connection string)

Comment: Have you tried to login with SMSS using the application user? Maybe the login is not mapped to the user, which happens sometimes when restoring backups?

Comment: OK, it seems a good idea, I'll test it, thanks, you mean entering connection string username/password in SSMS login page?

Comment: Exactly, that way you can see which schemas and tables the application can access.